# Override single css style / tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've got a big React app, which is now using Material UI 4.3.0.

I was trying to remove the `margin-top` style of `label + .MuiInput-formControl`. (It is a `select` mui component)
I used the 'overrides' tag in my App.js, as I have before, doing

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
overrides: {
 MuiInput: {
  formControl: {
   "label + &": {
    marginTop: "0",
   }
  }
 }
},
...
}
```

And it worked just fine... but it broke every other time I used the same component, as expected.
In my current, working file where I want to change margin, I'm having a hard time overriding the default styles. What is the correct way to override it?

I've tried overriding with classes, unsuccessfully, tried to do `const styles = theme => ({ overrides.... etc` as i wrote on the createmuitheme above, and tried with inline style.

I know there is a correct way to do it, but i'm not experienced enough to find it. An incorrect, but working way to do it, was to wrap the component in a div and using negative margins on it, but i'm looking to correct it the right way, as it is going to be useful later on too.

Thanks!

---

Edit: Component that i'm trying to style

```
renderFormats(){
 const { formats } = this.state;
 var formatsDOM = undefined;
 if(formats !== undefined && this.state.selectedFormat !== undefined){
  formatsDOM =
   <Select
    value={this.state.selectedFormat}
    onChange={this.onExportChange.bind(this)}
    disabled={!this.state.customFormatIsSelected}                                    
    inputProps={{
    name: 'Format',
    id: 'FormatInput',                                                           
    }}                                                                               
   >
   {formats.map( format => this.renderFormatEntry(format))}                         
  </Select>                                                                            
 }
return formatsDOM;                                                                           
}
```

Comment: If you are using `Select` instead of `TextField`, then it means the `FormControl` and `InputLabel` are being controlled separately by your code. Please include that code as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `TextField`, then you need to specify the `formControl` class via `InputProps`. If you are using the lower-level components (`FormControl`, `InputLabel`, and `Select`) explicitly, then you need a custom `Input` component (called `InputNoMargin` in my example) with the `formControl` class specified and then specify that component using the `input` property of `Select`.

Below is an example which applies this styling to a text input `TextField`, a select `TextField`, and a "composed" `Select` using the lower-level components.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  formControl: {
    "label + &": {
      marginTop: 0
    }
  }
});

const currencies = [
  {
    value: "USD",
    label: "$"
  },
  {
    value: "EUR",
    label: "€"
  },
  {
    value: "BTC",
    label: "฿"
  },
  {
    value: "JPY",
    label: "¥"
  }
];

const InputNoMargin = props => {
  const inputClasses = useStyles(props);
  return <Input {...props} classes={inputClasses} />;
};
export default function TextFields() {
  const inputClasses = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    name: "Cat in the Hat",
    currency: "EUR"
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <TextField
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        value={values.name}
        InputProps={{ classes: inputClasses }}
        onChange={handleChange("name")}
        margin="normal"
      />
      <br />
      <TextField
        id="standard-select-currency"
        select
        label="Select"
        value={values.currency}
        onChange={handleChange("currency")}
        InputProps={{ classes: inputClasses }}
        helperText="Please select your currency"
        margin="normal"
      >
        {currencies.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
      <br />
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="composed-select">Composed Select</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={values.currency}
          onChange={handleChange("currency")}
          inputProps={{ id: "composed-select", name: "composed-select" }}
          input={<InputNoMargin />}
        >
          {currencies.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit TextField and Select Input classes]

Comment: You're right i was not showing enough code. I want to edit the 'Select' MUI component, I edited my post and added the component itself.

Comment: I've added another case to my example using `Select`.